# powershell exporting to text file

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm working on a script that checks folders in specific directory. For example, I run the script  for first time, it generates me a txt file containing folders in the directory.

I need the script to add any new directories that are found to the previously created txt file when the script is run again.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to make that happen?

Here is my code so far:

```
$LogFolders = Get-ChildItem -Directory mydirectory ;


If (-Not (Test-Path -path "txtfilelocated")) 

 {

Add-Content txtfilelocated -Value $LogFolders 
break;

}else{

$File = Get-Content "txtfilelocatedt"

$File | ForEach-Object {
$_ -match $LogFolders
}

}
$File
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

You can specify what directory to check adding path to `get-childitem` cmdlet in first line

```
$a = get-childitem | ? { $_.psiscontainer } | select -expand fullname #for V2.0 and above
$a = get-childitem -Directory | select -expand fullname #for V3.0 and above

if ( test-path .\list.txt )
{    
  compare-object (gc list.txt) ($a) -PassThru | Add-Content .\list.txt
}
else
{    
 $a | set-content .\list.txt    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Everything is working! Thank you!